# How to mantain Shell_reverse_tcp connection?

Tags: shell, cmd, metasploit

I'm experimenting with reverse shell tcp. I managed to establish a connection, but my question is, how do I mantain a connection even after I close the multihandler? And when I'm using the target's command prompt, how do I send files to the target's computer using his command prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pedro,

The short answer is you can't.

- In order to maintain a connection you need to install persistence on
  the victim machine. You will still have to reuse the multi/handler in
  order to receive a new connection.
- In order to transfer files you need to use the meterpreter payload in
  order to upload and download files.
- However, if you have powershell on your target machine you can run a
  powershell download that will fetch internet hosted resources for
  you.

Hope this helped.